# Can Chrome Extension’s new options_ui trigger a page action?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I’ve been placing a page action on the options page of my Chrome extension.  `options.js` calls `chrome.runtime.connect({"name":"someName"})`, and `background.js` has

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(port.sender.tab.id);
});
```

Unfortunately, in the new options_ui with the recommended default (and someday mandatory) `"open_in_tab":false`, [the Sender's tab won't be set](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/optionsV2#messaging-api).  Is there a way to get the tab id in order to show the page action?

I could use [tabs.query](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query) to get the `chrome://extensions/` tab, but that requires the `tabs` permission, which I currently don’t need.  Active tab seems like it would work, but it doesn’t provide the tab id and isn’t enabled by opening an option dialog ([source](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab#what-activeTab-allows)).

(Why do I want the page action on my options page?  The extension works with a website that is only available ~7-10 weeks per year.  I’d like my users to be able to interact with the extension the rest of the time, so that they can get used to the process.  But I don’t want to adjust the displayed extension permissions just to do so.  I can accomplish this by having the options page pretend to be the website in question.)

Comment: `tabs.query` doesn't require the tabs permission. Just query with `url: 'chrome://extensions/?options=' + chrome.runtime.id` and you'll find the tab if it exists.

Comment: @RobW I hadn’t even thought to try that, embarrassingly enough.  Do you have a guess as to whether I should worry that “Chrome may change the embedding URL in the future”?  Or that `chrome` isn’t a permitted url scheme?

Comment: As far as I know, there are no plans to restrict `chrome.tabs.query` for `chrome://` URLs. `?options=` is likely going to be stable as well, but you could add wildcards just in case: `chrome://extensions/?*options=id*`.

Comment: For anyone coming across this later, it looks like `tabs.query` now needs the tabs permission to test the url.